# Redux state is null on page reload

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

I am learning react universal rendering with redux. I am following https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example to include SSR feature in my react-redux webapp. The differences in my architecture are, I am not using Ducks modules as in the example. I am also using isomorphic-fetch instead of superagent. And I am not using any promise middleware since fetch itself return promise to async connect. So my async call looks something like this

```
/* App.js */
@asyncConnect([{
promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}}) => {
    let promises = [];
    promises.push(dispatch(getUserProfile()));
    return Promise.all(promises);
    }
}])

class App extends Component {
...
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        userProfile: state.userProfile
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

/* userAction.js */
export function getUserProfile() {
return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const email = getState().userProfile.email;
    dispatch({type: actions.GET_USER_PROFILE});
    return fetch(constants.BASE_API_URL + urls.GET_USER_PROFILE, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: commonHeaders,
        body: JSON.stringify({ email })
    })
    .then(checkHttpStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(jsonResponse => {
        dispatch({
            type: actions.GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
            sessionId
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({
            type: actions.GET_USER_PROFILE_FAILED,
            errorMessage: error.message
        });
    });
};
}
```

But I am facing a strange issue. I have a popup for sign in in my app (not from router). And the api call for signing in is completely handled on client side. After signing in I am storing user email in redux state. But when I refresh the browser, all the values in redux state become null.
So I get null for `getState().userProfile.email` in the `userAction.js`.

All I want is to retain the state on page reload (server rendering). I have searched a lot for any solution. But couldn't figure out anything. I may be missing something in the redux flow.

Comment: React/Redux state is lost on page reload, you might want to get the state from somewhere else, that's why `componentWillMount` exist, to fetch and set the data in the state before mounting.

Comment: You're *rendering* on the server, but redux is being used on the client side right?

Comment: Ok. I'll check with componentWillMount.

Comment: One thing I could not understand. How the redux state is maintained globally in @erikras' example. Because after logging in, the state is not null on page reload in the example. How this function is working? While in my case globalState(`store.getState()`) is null.
`export function isLoaded(globalState) { return globalState.auth && globalState.auth.loaded; }`